# "An error occurred during execution; please try again later."

Tags: error, plugin, setup

I installed a module called FireGento MageSetup2, and then didn't need it anymore.

I then disabled it, uninstalled it then removed it from the composer.

However, when trying to load the Web Setup, spinning error occures due to a 500 error at /setup/index.php/componentGrid/components

This is the message shown:

[image: Error message]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

King regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by searching for all instances of the plugin name in my Magento files. I removed all relevant code to the compiler and module, then ran the upgrade and compile commands.

This fixed my issue as I had removed any occurrence of the module.